# Android Studio :How to solve this execution error

Tags: java, android

I am new to android studio, and I don't understand why my app crash when I start using the seekbar.
Could someone please help me?

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SeekBar seekBar; //declare seekbar object
    TextView textView, textView2;
    ListView simpleListview;
    //declare member variables for SeekBar
    int discrete;
    int start = 50;
    int start_position = 50;
    //progress tracker
    int temp = 0;
    //declare objects for ViewStub
    ViewStub stub;
    CheckBox checkBox;
    ListView lv; //declare Listview object
    Button button;
    View view;

```
public MainActivity() {
    discrete = 0;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //declare viewstub object
    stub = findViewById(R.id.viewStub1);
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    View inflated = stub.inflate();
    stub.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    //ViewStub logic
    checkBox = findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    //handle checkbox click event
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                //remove objs from parent view to allow for child view objs
                checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                seekBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                stub.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }
    });
    //seekbar logic
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textview);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    textView.setText(" Celsius at 0 degrees");



    //set default view
    seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
    seekBar.setProgress(start_position);


    //create event handler for SeekBar
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            if (temp == 0) {
                //for initial view result
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Fahrenheit result: 32 degrees",
                        //Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                textView2.setText("Fahrenheit result 32 degrees") ;

            }
            else{
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Fahrenheit result: "
                        //+ String.valueOf(discrete) +
                        //" degrees",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                textView2.setText("Fahrenheit result:" + String.valueOf(discrete) + "degrees");
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar){ }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar,
                                      int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            // To convert progress passed as discrete (Fahrenheit) value
            temp = progress - start;
            discrete = (int) Math.round((((temp * 9.0) /
                    5.0) + 32));
            //convert C to F temp textView.setText(" Celsius at " + temp + " degrees");
            textView.setText(" Celsius at " + temp + " degrees");
        }

    });
```

Comment: Can you share the error log

Answer (score 2):

```
textView = findViewById(R.id.textview);
textView = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

textView2 is not initialised here...

Change above code to

```
textView = findViewById(R.id.textview);
textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

Answer (score 0):

TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textview);
    TextView textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);

Answer (score 0):

initialize textView2
You seem to have missed that part

Comment: thank you(sorry for the delay of my answer, the last time it did not upload)